# How can I fix the error I got while trying to make a simple rotation animation in React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to rotate a simple box in react native. But when I set up the algorithm below it gives the error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'value.getValue')". The other I tried to do was give the same error when using Animated.spring How can I solve it?

**App.js**

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Animated, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const animatedValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(animatedValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 1000,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  });

  const animatedStyle = {
    transform: [
      {
        rotate: interpolateRotation,
      },
    ],
  };
  

  const interpolateRotation = animatedValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg'],
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.box, animatedStyle]}>
        <Text style={styles.Text}>Spinner</Text>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  box: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 100,
    left: 100,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'blue',
  },
  Text: {
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

[image]

any help is appreciated

Comment: I think you have to place const interpolateRotation before the const animatedStyle.

Comment: Yes you are right,Thank you